# get specific part of url using regex

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a URL

```
ws://mydomain.com/auth/mZFZN4yc/?rtmpUrl=rtmp://abc.com/live/0q4wwjye
```

How can i get the auth string "**mZFZN4yc**" from this.

I have used in NodeJS

```
req.url.match(/^\/auth\/(.*)$/)
```

but it is returning this whole part

```
mZFZN4yc/?rtmpUrl=rtmp://abc.com/live/0q4wwjye
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.*` you can use `[^\/]+`, so you get it all up to the `/`, like:

```
req.url.match(/\/auth\/([^\/]+)/)
```

Comment: Alos i found another way as second step. to split it using req.url.match(/^\/auth\/(.*)$/).split("/?")[0]